# submit mvc form using swal alerts to a function with parameters

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to submit a form to a a controller. However, I get this error

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'btnSend' of non-nullable type 'System.DateTime' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult CashDelivery(System.DateTime)' in 'TelyPayMVC_CODE.Controllers.TelecomeController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
```

the funcion in the controller has 3 parameters but I don't know how to submit it.
Here is the script

```
<script>
$('#btn-submit').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this).parents('form');
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "You will not be able to recover this task!",
        type: "info",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, Send it!",
        closeOnConfirm: false
    }, function (isConfirm) {
        if (isConfirm) form.submit();
    });
});
```

and this is the head of the function

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CashDelivery(DateTime btnSend, DateTime endOfPeriod, int companyID)
```

and finally this is the form i need to submit

```
using (Html.BeginForm("CashDelivery", "Telecome"))
{
  <input name="endOfPeriod" value="@pay.Item1.AddDays(6)" hidden="hidden" />
  <input name="companyID" value="1" hidden="hidden" />
   <button type="button" name="btnSend" value="@pay.Item1" class="btn btn-block btn-xs btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" id="btn-submit"> <i class="fa fa-check"></i> </button>
}
```

can anyone help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following in hidden field and don't set it in button's value

**EDIT**:

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CashDelivery", "Telecome"))
{
<input name="endOfPeriod" value="@pay.Item1.AddDays(6)" hidden="hidden" />
<input name="companyID" value="1" hidden="hidden" />
<input name="btnSend" value="" @pay.Item1 " hidden="hidden" />
<button type="button" name="btn-submit" value="BlahBlah" class="btn btn-block btn-xs btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" id="btn-submit"> <i class="fa fa-check"></i> </button>
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CashDelivery(FormCollection form)
{

     DateTime endOfPeriod = Convert.ToDateTime(form["endOfPeriod"]);
     DateTime btnSend = Convert.ToDateTime(form["btnSend"]);
     int companyID = Convert.ToInt32(form["companyID"]);
     //your logic goes here
}
```

Comment: thank you mate, I will, but what i need now is to know how to send this value to the action in the controller. @TejasVaishnav

Comment: MVC posts each element of form by its name to server so after applying my solution, let me know if you are not receiving value in action

Comment: yes it did work ,, I should lough on myself :), thanks a lot my friend @TejasVaishnav